# What is the quickest way to get a car from London to Iceland?

Tags: london, ferries, automobiles, iceland

I am considering going to Iceland and was wondering if it is feasible to take there my car with me. The only way to get there by ferry that I could find is described [here](http://www.seat61.com/Iceland.htm), which suggests getting to Denmark first (which is in the opposite direction), and then getting a slow ferry from there. Is there a better way?

Comment: Some years ago, I found a ferry that goes from Scrabster (Scotland) to Iceland. It only operates in summer. No idea if it still exists.

Comment: The Smyril ferry that the below answers mention used to stop at Lerwick or Scrabster. They stopped doing this in 2008.

Comment: A comment as I'm not directly addressing the question - I've hired a car in Iceland in winter, and it was affordable (similar to UK prices) AND came with snow tyres fitted. You would be mad to drive there without snow tyres at certain times of the year.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only ferry to Iceland is the weekly ferry from Denmark. It takes a while and you spend two nights aboard each way (and incidentally get the opportunity to visit the Faeroe Islands along the way).

The ferry is *not* guaranteed to run during winter (it mostly carries cargo during the winter months, if there is cargo going to Iceland you can book a trip, but only shortly before departure).

The ferry is also rather expensive, so for a short trip (anything under a week certainly) you would likely find it cheaper to fly and then rent a car. This will also save you 4 days at sea, which would eat into any shorter trip.

Answer (score 12):

The only car ferry to Iceland leaves from Hirtshals, Denmark, so you have to somehow get to Denmark first. So the fastest way is to drive to Dover, take the Channel tunnel to Calais, then travel over Antwerp, Duisburg and Hamburg to Hirtshals. There take the car ferry to Reykjavik.

London→Hirtshals takes approximately [14 hours](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=London,%20United%20Kingdom&daddr=Hirtshals,%20Denmark&hl=en&ll=54.149567,14.963379&spn=14.120931,47.878418&sll=57.751219,-10.9226&sspn=12.876385,47.878418&geocode=FaHzEQMd-wv-_yl13iGvC6DYRzGZKtXdWjqWUg;FQm1bgMd9hSYAClNjvxQSchIRjGp5AEmapCaEw&oq=Hirtsha&vpsrc=6&mra=ls&t=m&z=6).

Hirtshals→Reykjavik really depends on the weather and the season, but you should at least calculate [80 hours](http://highways-denmark.com/hirtshals-faroe-islands-iceland/).

It also depends on the further development. Until recently, you had to wait two days on the Faeroe island. But this has changed, but it is not sure if it will be so in the future.